# Webpack loader: inline or embed the required, omit a final jsonp functions

Tags: webpack

Let's suppose the next files:

**a.html**

```html
<span>A</span>
```

**b.js**

```js
module.exports = function(){};
```

**wrap.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  html: require('./a.html'), // to be inlined
  class: require('wrap-class'), // does not exists
  func: require('./b'),
};
```

**main.js**

```js
require('./wrap');
```

Let's suppose the next loader:

**wrap-loader.js**

```js
module.exports = function (source){
  // I would like to get the loaded contents
  // from specific childs or dynamically loaded
  // require('./a.html') -> inlined or embedded
  // require('class-exists') -> resolve to something depending on the
  // source code `source` and the contents of the html (`a.html`)
  return source; // modify the source
}
```

And finally, I would like to have when requiring `main.js` as a bundle:

```js
jsonp(...,[
  /* 0 */ /* ./main.js */
  function(module, exports, __webpack_require__){
    __webpack_require__(/*! ./wrap.js */ 1);
  },
  /* 1 */ /* ./wrap.js */
  function(module, exports, __webpack_require__){
    module.exports = {
      html: '<span>A</span>',
      class: 'cls-wrap cls-based-on-a-html-and-wrap-js',
      func: __webpack_require_(/*! ./b.js */ 2),
    }
  },
  /* 2 */ /* ./b.js */
  function(module, exports, __webpack_require__){
    module.exports = function(){};
  }
]);
```

**Question**

How can I achieve:

1. that specific `require` inside my current `source` in `wrap-loader.js` are inlined or embedded in the `source` itself, without generating a new function (let's say, because it won't be reused by any other, and in that case, it could inline again). In the above example: `a.html`.
2. that a `source`in `wrap-loader.js` resolves dynamically a module based on other data (eg. the `source` itself, and the contents of `a.html`) and inserts them in the `source` (where it was the `require('wrap-class')`).

**Trials**

`this.resolveSync` and `this.resolve` but they don't get the same contents as `require('something')` in the code (eg. yaml-loader, html-loader are loaded like javascript, at least emit errors).